# Format cell as days plus time duration

Tags: microsoft-excel, date-time, cell-format

In Excel I have cells that contain durations, stored as date (integer part) plus time (fraction) as usual. Now I would like to format the values to see the number of elapsed days plus the remaining hours and minutes, e.g. **34 days and 13:37**.

I tried all [cell formats](https://docs.microsoft.com/office/troubleshoot/excel/format-cells-settings) I could think of. I *can* format as total number of hours and minutes elapsed (`[u]:mm`: 829:37) for instance:

```
FORMAT         34,56789      but:

[u]:mm         829:37        how many days is that?
d u:mm         3 13:37       incomplete for 32+
j-m-d u:mm     00-2-3 13:37  month is 1 too high :-(
[d] u:mm       #VALUE!       [d] not understood :-(
0 u:mm         #VALUE!       cannot combine number and date/time formats :-(
0,00           34,57         translate the decimals into hours by hand :-(
not possible?  34 13:37      this is what I would like!
```

Note that formats and results use Dutch regional settings here. US would use `y` instead of `j`, `h` instead of `u` and `.` instead of `,`.

So... I cannot format it like `34 13:37`?

Of course I could use a formula, but that would take an extra column in my case.

Comment: There is no INTERVAL datatype with days part in MS Excel...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I settled for:

```
[>31,9999942071759]0,0" days";[$-020000]d" days "u:mm
```

using Dutch regional settings.

For US that would be:

```
[>31.9999942071759]0.0" days";[$-020000]d" days "h:mm
```

This format switches between `31 days 23:59` (for precision) and `32.0 days` automatically.

For seconds add `:ss` at the end.

The `[$-020000]` specifies the Gregorian calendar, which works up until 31 full days.

Answer (score 1):

`34.56789` is producing `3 13:37` using `d hh:mm` because the 34th day of the year is February 3rd and `d` is the mask for day-of-the-month.

There is no day-of-the-year format mask but you could use `0` for the integer. However, you cannot pair `0` with time formats like `hh` or `mm`.

Two TEXT functions concatenated together could produce the results in another cell but I believe you want to use cell formatting; that's not possible.

```
=text(int(a1), "0 ")&text(a1, "hh:mm")
'result
34 13:37
```

Comment: *because the 34th day of the year is February 3rd* more precisely February 3, 1900.

Comment: @Akina - Or *'because the 34th day of the year **1900** is February 3rd ...'* but yes, you're correct. Since the first 34 days-of-the-year are the same for every year and I was trying to explain that *d* represents *day-of-the-month*, I didn't think it was necessary to add that.